# Vue JS waiting for data before rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

I'm stuck since a few weeks in a problem with rendering data with VueJS.

What I'm doing is making some axios calls (one inside another). My problem is that the data is rendered before the calls has completed, so the view is not showing anything.

I saw some codes that do some "await" and "Async calls" but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Also there is something similar here
[Get component to wait for asynchronous data before rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477230/get-component-to-wait-for-asynchronous-data-before-rendering)
But isn't working either

here is my code:

```html
    <template>
     <div class="m-portlet m-portlet--full-height" m-portlet="true" id="m_portlet_validate_agenda">
    ...
    <div class="m-portlet__body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="m_widget2_tab1_diagnose">
                <div class="m-widget2">
                    <div v-for="diagnose in diagnoses" v-if="diagnoses.length" :class="'m-widget2__item m-widget2__item--' + diagnose.delayColor[0]">
                        <div class="m-widget2__checkbox" >
                            <label class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--solid m-checkbox--single m-checkbox--brand">
                                <span class="m--bg-white" v-html="diagnose.concurrence"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-widget2__agenda col-2">
                            {{ diagnose.started_at | moment("HH:mm A") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-widget2__desc" v-if="!isFetching">
                            <div>
                                <span class="m-widget2__text">

                                </span><br>
                                <span class="m-widget2__user-name">
                                    <a href="#" class="m-widget2__link m-link">
                                    Paciente: 
                                    {{ diagnose.details[0].name }}
                                    </a><br>
                                    <a href="#" class="m-widget2__link m-link">
                                    Tratante: 

                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                events: [],
                diagnoses: [],
                urgencies: [],
                treatments: [],
                isFetching: true
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.loadData();
        },

        methods: {

            loadData: async function() {
                await axios.get('/pacientes/request-json/agenda/validarAsistencia/eventos').then(res => {
                    this.events = res.data;
                    this.diagnoses = [];
                    this.urgencies = [];
                    this.treatments = [];
                    this.getDetails();
                    this.getDelayColor();
                    this.getConcurrence();
                    vm.$nextTick(function () {
                        $('[data-toggle="m-tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    });
                    console.log('end LoadData');
                });
            },

            getDetails: function() {
                console.log('cargando');
                this.events.forEach(event => {
                    axios.get('/pacientes/request-json/agenda/validarAsistencia/eventos/' + event.id).then(res => {
                        event.details = res.data;
                        console.log(res.data);
                    });
                });
                this.distributeEvents();
                console.log('montado');
            },    

            distributeEvents: function() {
                this.events.forEach(event => {
                    if ( event.event.event_type == "diagnosis" )
                    {
                        this.diagnoses.push(event);
                    }
                    else if ( event.event.event_type == "urgency" )
                    {
                        this.urgencies.push(event);
                    }    
                    else if ( event.event.event_type == "treatment" )
                    {
                        this.treatments.push(event);
                    }
                });
                this.isFetching = false;
            },

            getDelayColor: function() {
                this.events.forEach(event => {
                    do something...
                });
            },

            getConcurrence: function() {
                this.events.forEach(event => {                    
                    do something...
                });
            },

            diffMinutes: function(started_at) {
                do something...
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't handling Promises properly, so they keep getting **unresolved**. You can use `async`, `await`, although I prefer myself using plain [Promise Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

`getDetails()` is another story. You are making a loop, and `forEach` loop you are sending an **axios** request. You could have to store each **Promise** returned by each **axios** call in an array, to call then **Promise.all**.

```js
    getDetails: function() {
        let url = '/pacientes/request-json/agenda/validarAsistencia/eventos/';
        console.log('loading');
        let promisedEvents = [];

        this.events.forEach(event => {
            promisedEvents.push(axios.get(url + event.id))
        });

        return Promise.all(promisedEvents)
    },
```

After that I would do something like this:

```js
    loadData: function() {
        axios.get('/pacientes/request-json/agenda/validarAsistencia/eventos')
            .then(res => {
                this.events = res.data;
                this.getDelayColor() // sync operation; no need to be returned
                return this.getDetails(); // Return the promise(s)
            })
            .then((res) => {
                // do something with the response from your array of Promises
            })
            .then(anotherPromise) // You can also return a promise like this 
            .catch(handleError) // Very important to handle your error!!
        });
    },
```

I am not saying this is the best way to achieve what you may want, but that it is one way to make your code to work. Important here is that you need to learn about Promises.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, I also will read something about promises

Comment: Let me know if you need help to clarify something!

Comment: Also, hablo español. :)

Comment: there are a bunch of documentation that discuss about to prefer async/await instead of promises

Comment: @Pablo Araya Sure, but you should understand promises [before jumping in async/await](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8). In the end, I like personally more the syntax of **Promises** more.

Answer (score 32):

To prevent the component from rendering before the data have returned you could:

1. add a "isFetching" property to the data and set it to "true"
2. in the fetch callback, set isFetching to "false"

3.add v-if="!isFetching" to the wrapper of the component

Comment: Should I need to implement a watcher also ??

Comment: no, The "isFetching" property is in the 'data' object, meaning that vue watching it for us, and will update the component automatically once changed. no watch needed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either...
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: diagnose.details is undefined"

Comment: Move the 'v-if="!isFetching"' to the wrapper, the first div in the component. Or at least to to wrap the access to the variable in the template

Answer (score 1):

The Solution:

Thanks you guys !

```
         loadData: function() {
            axios.get('/pacientes/request-json/agenda/validarAsistencia/eventos')
                .then(res => {
                    this.events = res.data;
                    this.getDelayColor() // sync operation; no need to be returned
                    this.getConcurrence();
                    vm.$nextTick(function () {
                        $('[data-toggle="m-tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    });
                    return this.getDetails(); // Return the promise(s)
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        this.events[i].details = res[i].data;
                    }
                    this.distributeEvents();
                    console.log('end LoadData');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error');
                })
        },

        getDetails: function() {
            let url = '/pacientes/request-json/agenda/validarAsistencia/eventos/';
            let promisedEvents = [];

            this.events.forEach(event => {
                promisedEvents.push(axios.get(url + event.id))
            });

            return Promise.all(promisedEvents)
        },
```