# How to wait for data in component before rendering in Vue+typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

In first component I open new page using router
**Component_1.vue:**

```
let route = this.$router.resolve({ name: 'Schedule', params : { id: (this.schedule[0].schedule_id).toString() } });
window.open(route.href, '_blank');
```

**router.ts:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import SchedulePage from "./views/SchedulePage.vue"

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      // here is other routes
    },
    {
      path: "/schedule/:id",
      name: "Schedule",
      component: SchedulePage,
    },
  ]
});
```

**SchedulePage.vue**

This component render before `schedule` gets from async function.
How to solve this problem? Yeah, I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024406/vue-js-waiting-for-data-before-rendering), but I don't understand how store and return promises from `created()` or `getSchedule()`

```
<template>
  <schedule-table
    v-if = "schedule.length > 0"
    :exercises="schedule.exercises"
  />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import store from "@/store"

import Vue from 'vue';
import ScheduleTable from '../components/ScheduleTable.vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { ISchedule }  from "@/interfaces";
import * as api from '@/api';


export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    ScheduleTable,
  },

  data(){
    return {
      schedule : {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSchedule : async function () {
      this.schedule = await api.getScheduleById( this.$route.params.id );
    }
  },
  async created(){
    await this.getSchedule();
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your v-if should be something like `v-if="Object.keys(schedule).length"`. Apart from that, why is rendering the component problematic even if you don't have the data yet? Putting a v-if like you did looks good to me.

Comment: @Phil if component empty, methods in it wiil be work with errors. This component should show only with data

Comment: @Phil You right, I shouldn't lenght method of object. It's work if use `Object.entries(schedule).length != 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks *Phill* for help. I'm wrong in

```
<schedule-table
    v-if = "schedule.length > 0"
    :exercises="schedule.exercises"
/>
```

`schedule` isn't array, it's object.
Better to use something like this

`object.entries(schedule).length != 0`

[More info about testing objects for emptiness here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)